# I have an issue with using stripe API for send payments to my customers bank account

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to send payments to my customers bank account using stripe API.

I have used `createExternalAccount` API. Please help me out from this situation.

Error I got below:

> The provided key 'sk_live_oj**********************' does not have the
>   required permissions for this endpoint on account 'acct_************'.
>   Having more permissions would allow this request to continue.

Comment: There is not enough information in this post for you to get a good answer. We need to see what you have tried, what has worked, what has not worked, and any errors you get. Please see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question so you get better answers.

Comment: Please tell us what have you tried so far, write snippets of your code where you're calling the API

Comment: There are two things wrong with this. Why are you testing with sk_live instead of sk_test keys. Secondly, it looks like your capabilities are not correctly set when creating the account.

Comment: As noted above, you should be testing with a test key `sk_test_xxx`, and we need more details to offer suggestions. Can you share a snippet of your code? Is this the error message copied verbatim?

I suspect you are trying to modify an account that does not belong to your platform. Are you sure the account exists and that your platform can modify it?